# QGIS - link the extent and rotation of each map

Tags: qgis, layouts

How to link the extent and rotation of each map window to the sheet-sections?
I asume the atlas function does not apply in this scenario?

[image: sheetsection]

[image: layout]

Comment: i might add, that two mapwindows are displayed on one sheet in the layout.

Comment: Sorry, not clear what you want to do. Can you provide a bit more information?

Comment: I have a sheet-section-layer 'Blattschnitt', with a certain extension and rotation for each polygone, that has his own attributes, like the name 'Blatt_1' and 'Blatt__2" and even calculated rotation.

Now, in the layout, i would like the seperate mapwindows (the upper and the lower one) to be controlled by the geometries of the single polygones (Blatt 1 and Blatt 2) from the layer 'Blattschnitte'

hope my translation was clearer now and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want item `Map2` to follow the extent/rotation of item `Map1`

Set the Map2 properties to custom variables like:

Rotation:   `map_get( item_variables('Map 1'),'map_rotation')`

X_min:      `x_min(map_get( item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent'))`

Y_min:      `y_min(map_get( item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent'))`

X_max:      `x_max(map_get( item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent'))`

Y_max:      `y_max(map_get( item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent'))`

[image]

Changes to Map1 will automatically be reflected on Map2
[image]

You can use a similar approach with updated formulas to compute a specific frame for `Map2` based on `Map1`

Comment: Hello Kasper, thank you for the great explenation. I am not sure if it is what i wanted... I have a layer 'Blattschnitte' with two polygons defining the extent and rotation of the area of interrest... but devided into two sections. I would like the upper mapwindow to be controled by 'Blatt 1' of the 'Blattschnitte'-Layer and the lower one by 'Blatt 2'.

Comment: Ok, will look at it tomorrow, but it should be easy if you want to dig into it to retrieve the geometry from Blatt1 & 2 and use these polygons as references in the Map1 & 2 extents

Comment: that would be fantastic! Thank you :)

Comment: Not as straightforward than I thought. Will keep pushing but not sure to find out. You might want to clarify the question & title to possibly get other answers